# What does "See me" mean when written on a student's assignment?

Tags: questions

What does the  phrase "See me" mean?  This was written on the student's finished assignment.

Comment: The teacher wants you to meet with them after class to discuss the assignment.

Comment: @Wendi, in the U.S., is it common that a teacher writes "see me" on the student's assignment. I ask because, as far as I know, Italian teachers don't use to do so, and if they did it would seem strange at best.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Yeah, I'd say it's rather common. Often you're passing back everyone's assignment/test at once, and you don't want to call attention to the fact that a single student needs special attention in front of the whole class. Usually it's when you've done poorly on an assignment ("You didn't do well, we need to talk about that") but in theory it could also be used for something positive ("This was a great essay, I want you to submit it to this writing competition!"). You can usually tell which by the score at the top of the paper.

Comment: @Wendi, thank you, but, alas, the Italian school, as institution, is quite poor in regard to competition and this is causing the regression of Italy among underdeveloped countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [imperative](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/imperative/menu.php) (an *order/instruction*) with the implied subject ***you*** omitted. Basically, it means...

> "[You are instructed to come and] **see me**". *(because I want to talk to you about your assignment)*

---

Back when I was at school (a *long* time ago! :) *"See me"* was a pretty common thing for teachers to write in your homework book. And *"See me after class"* was a common instruction given to disruptive pupils (who would normally expect a severe ["telling off"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/telling-off) for whatever behaviour caused them to be singled out).

Context is everything, but I expect most students would rather *not* find *"See me"* on their homework. Most likely they'll be getting some [potentially lengthy] complaint, rather than praise or in-depth discussion.